# Backup specific WhatsApp Chat to Google Photos

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-photos

Any way to backup specific WhatsApp Chat's media (a group's media) to Google Photos? I can only see WhatsApp Images folder in GPhotos. I can't see any other way to do this.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

I'm on Android 10 with root-access